# PostgreSQL: show the several max rows for each group?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need count 3 maximum value for each **user(user_id)** for each **way**.

My table:

```
> db=# SELECT * FROM test;

     id | user_id    | value    | way
    ----+------------+----------+------
      1 |          1 | 10       | 1
      2 |          2 | 30       | 1
      3 |          3 | 20       | 1
      4 |          1 | 50       | 2
      5 |          2 | 40       | 2
      6 |          3 | 60       | 2
      7 |          2 | 70       | 3
      8 |          4 | 5        | 1
    (8 rows)
```

Table that I need:

```
user_id | MAX1       | MAX2     | MAX3
    ----+------------+----------+------
      1 |          0 | 1        | 1
      2 |          2 | 0        | 1
      3 |          1 | 1        | 0
      4 |          1 | 0        | 0
```

i. e. **user_id 2** has maximum value on **way 1, way 3** and the third maximum on **way 3**. **user_id 1** has second maximum on **way 2** and third maximum on **way 1**.
etc.

Please help me create right query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `row_number partitioned by way order by value` within a `cte`;

```
with cte as(
   select 
          id,
          user_id,val,
          row_number() over(partition by way order by val desc) rank,
          val,
          way      
   from test)
   select distinct cte2.user_id,
          (select count(*) from cte where cte.rank=1 and cte.user_id=cte2.user_id) as MAX1,
          (select count(*) from cte where cte.rank=2 and cte.user_id=cte2.user_id) as MAX2,
          (select count(*) from cte where cte.rank=3 and cte.user_id=cte2.user_id) as MAX3
   from cte cte2 where rank<=3
   order by 1
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fa7ab/10)

Comment: I try your query! It s work, but user_id 4, not showing.

Comment: @Jurik, please see the sample input data again, user_id=4 has 4'th value in way=1 and it is in only way=1, so it has neither max1 neither max2 neither max3, according to your input data and description, the last record in your desired output is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can come to understanding this question is that it is just conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id,
       sum(case when way = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as way1,
       sum(case when way = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as way2,
       sum(case when way = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as way3
from test
group by user_id;
```

I note that your original data has 8 rows and the numbers in the result set add up to 8.  I have no idea what "max" is for.